# Effective way to detect current Audio Route in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

My application requires the ability to know the fundamental audio route the user has selected. On iOS this is trivial, as you just register for a callback and you know exactly where the audio is going.

On Android I was pleased to see the `MediaRouter` class, however to my dismay it turns out there is no predictable way to determine the route type. For example, when switching to a Bluetooth A2DP device, the only identifying item is the `RouteInfo.getName()` method, but this returns the friendly name of the A2DP device, so it is impossible to compare against.

I also have tried using the following broadcasts:

```
AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY
Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG
BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED
BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
```

However this method is error prone. For example, if you are connected to Bluetooth A2DP, then you plug in headphones, it is easy to tell the route is "Headphones", but then when un-plugging the headphones you have to guess what route is still active, by recording the connected state from all Bluetooth events.

There are also difficulties in ascertaining the initial audio route when your application starts. HEADSET_PLUG is sticky, so that's good, but nothing else is...

Any suggestions on how to approach this and accurately detect this? And why is this such a difficult task in Android?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very hackish way of polling for the current route, which also supports detection of A2DP. Use at your own risk, as the interals of these classes could very well change in the future. It should work on Jellybean and Jellybean MR1, though.

```
String ouputDeviceName;
try {
    MediaRouter mr = (MediaRouter)getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
    Class mediaRouterClass = Class.forName("android.media.MediaRouter");
    Method getSystemAudioRouteMethod = mediaRouterClass.getMethod("getSystemAudioRoute");
    RouteInfo ri = (RouteInfo)getSystemAudioRouteMethod.invoke(mr);

    Class mediaRouterStaticClass = Class.forName("android.media.MediaRouter$Static");
    Field staticField = mediaRouterClass.getDeclaredField("sStatic");
    Field a2dpField = mediaRouterStaticClass.getDeclaredField("mBluetoothA2dpRoute");
    AccessibleObject.setAccessible(new AccessibleObject[]{staticField}, true);
    AccessibleObject.setAccessible(new AccessibleObject[]{a2dpField}, true);
    Object a2dpRoute = a2dpField.get(staticField.get(null));
    if (a2dpRoute != mr.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO)) {
        // Phone, Headphone, HDMI, etc..
        ouputDeviceName = "name: " + ri.getName().toString();
    } else {
        // Audio is routed to A2DP
        ouputDeviceName  = "name: A2DP";
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Does it matter if the Bluetooth route is using SCO or HFP, or are those handled by the first case?

Comment: I didn't check the result when the audio was routed to BT SCO, and I don't have a BT accessory available right now. Not sure if you'd get any kind of information from the MediaRouter class about routing to BT SCO - after all, you typically don't route media audio to BT SCO (unless you're doing media playback during a voice call).

Comment: Just looking through the MediaRouter source http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/media/MediaRouter.java#MediaRouter.Static.updateRoutes%28android.media.AudioRoutesInfo%29 they do not account for anything other than A2DP, and they simply use AudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn() -- I suppose if I find a route name that I do not recognize, I can check that method.